# Solve for parameter in ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions

I have a simple 2-variable ODE system with a parameter

$P'[z] = -2\Phi[z]$

$\Phi'[z] = -2\frac{P[z]}{a}$

I've implemented the code as follows

```
Pin = 20*10^5;

eqs = {P'[z] == -Phi[z], Phi'[z] == -Phi[z]/a};
bconds = {Phi[0] == 2, P[0] == Pin};
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqs, bconds}, {P, Phi}, {z, 0, 1},{a}]
```

How can I solve for this parameter so that $\Phi[1]$ is given by a specific $\Phi_{0}$. I've tried to define an inline function

```
EndPhi[x_] := (pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqs, bconds}, {P, Phi}, {z, 0, 1}, {a}];
xEnd = pfun[x][[1]][[1, 1, -1]]; 
pfun[x][[2]][xEnd]);
```

When I use

```
NSolve[EndPhi[x] == 0.2,x]
```

This does not lead to the solution. However, `EndPhi[x]` yields numbers for input values.

Comment: You need `FindRoot[]` with a good initial estimate; `NSolve[]` is not intended for this use.

Comment: Use `EndPhi[x_?
   NumericQ] := (pfun = 
    ParametricNDSolveValue[{eqs, bconds}, {P, Phi}, {z, 0, 1}, {a}];` instead

Comment: What is $\Phi_{0}$ and how is this related to $\Phi[1]$?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eqs, bconds}, {P, Phi}, {z, 0, 1}, {a}];

Plot[Evaluate[(Phi[a][1] - 2) /. sol], {a, 10^15, 10^16}]

FindRoot[(Phi[a][1] - 2) /. sol, {a, 10^15}]
```